# Multiple dygraphs in one row

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dygraphs

So I am very new at this whole Dygraph business and struggle to find a sollution. I'm trying to place two dygraphs side by side on a background canvas and it's just not working. 
I tried using display-inline property on the div for the graph on the right, float:left on the left div nad many other div arranging structures but none of them seems to work when I draw Dygraphs on them. Float:left was the onlj one that managed to put them both on a Canvas but made the left Dygraph uninteractive (I am thinking it's the downside of it being unanimatable).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" >
                <canvas class="canvas" id="cnv" width="140" height="60px" style="border:1px solid #999999;"></canvas>
                <div style="width:120px; height:65px; "> 
                    <div id="graphdiv2" style="width:60px; height:65px;"></div> 
                    <div id="graphdiv3" style="width:60px; height:65px;"></div>
                </div>    
            </div>
```

**JS:**

```
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
                 // For possible data formats, see http://dygraphs.com/data.html
                 // The x-values could also be dates, e.g. "2012/03/15"
                 "X,Y,Z\n" +
                 "1,0,3\n" +
                 "2,2,6\n" +
                 "3,4,8\n" +
                 "4,6,9\n" +
                 "5,8,9\n" +
                 "6,10,8\n" +
                 "7,12,6\n" +
                 "8,14,3\n",
                 {
                     // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
                     legend: 'always',
                     animatedZooms: true,
                     title: 'dygraphs chart template'
                 });

g2 = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
                 // For possible data formats, see http://dygraphs.com/data.html
                 // The x-values could also be dates, e.g. "2012/03/15"
                 "X,Y,Z\n" +
                 "1,0,3\n" +
                 "2,2,6\n" +
                 "3,4,8\n" +
                 "4,6,9\n" +
                 "5,8,9\n" +
                 "6,10,8\n" +
                 "7,12,6\n" +
                 "8,14,3\n",
                 {
                     // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
                     legend: 'always',
                     animatedZooms: true,
                     title: 'dygraphs chart template'
                 });
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so finally managed to find a satisfying sollution. For future reference for me it was the use of

```
display: inline-block;
```

on both of the divs which I draw dygraphs on.

For proper use they must have **width** parameter set to some value (at least for me it didn't work before that).

This is my div code now:

```
<div id="graphdiv3" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; display: inline-block;"></div>
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem. :)